# Single word for frequently reassessing a task or situation

Tags: single-word-requests

Is there a single word that means to reassess or reevaluate a situation at frequent intervals?

How about a two-word alliteration (e.g. "fail fast")?

Comment: It's often achieved by *polling*, but that's not quite what you asked for.

Comment: overreprioritization is probably a terrible word to coin

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Perhaps you can use ***monitor***. According to ***[Collins](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/monitor)***:

> ***Monitor***
>
> *noun*
>
> 1) a person or piece of equipment that warns, checks, controls, or keeps a continuous record of something
>
> *verb (transitive)*
>
> 10) to act as a monitor of
>      11) to observe or record (the activity or performance) of (an engine or other device)

Comment: Well, we've already got the (usually derogatory) derivation [***micromanage***](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Micromanagement), so it would seem quite reasonable to "coin" ***micromonitor*** if OP's wants to imply "monitor *excessively/obsessively*". In fact, here's an example found before the comment edit "grace period" ran out: [*Agents do not like it when the principal tries to micromanage or micromonitor their activities.*](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22micromonitor+their+activities%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1)

Answer (score 3):

An idomatic expression for this kind of vigilance is:

**to keep tabs on**

> To monitor; to keep track of; to watch. 
>   *If you are careful to keep tabs on your finances, you should be able to stay within a budget.*
>   *The police kept close tabs on him during the holidays.*

([Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/keep_tabs_on))